# Distinct on 2 different fields at same time

Tags: sql, performance

Is it possible to get unique results of 2 different fields in 1 query?

Ex. Table Criminal

- Criminal name
- Id No
- No of Crimes in Past
- father name
- state

is it posible to get Criminal having distinct value (No of Crimes) in Past and distinct name in a single query?

means crime No also should unique and name is also uniqe.

Comment: Are you saying you only want one example of each criminal with a particular number of past crimes.  So if criminal A and criminal B both have 3 past crimes, you only get A or B, but not both?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple distinct values in a query:

```
SELECT
 [Criminal name],
 [No of Crimes in Past]
GROUP BY 
 [Criminal name],
 [No of Crimes in Past]
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this won't give you distinct values in each column but rather distinct pairs.  That may be what the OP wants, though; it's unclear.